# Oracle get data from Windows Mobile SDK(Pocket PC)

Tags: windows, oracle, mobile, pocketpc

I am developing a windows app for windows mobile sdk(Pocket PC) on vs2008 with .NET FRAMEWORK 2.0 . I wanna get data from oracle to windows mobile SDK(Pocket PC). I try Oracle SQLite but it wont work. Do you have any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have also the same problem, But i resolve by using an API. It connect oracle db and device through (HttpWebRequest), it works 100%
In this case we need an apache/nginx server.
here is some examples
https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/System.Net/HttpWebRequest/-/php-httpwebrequest-class-examples.html